# How to: dynamic change action Buttons icon or put in a text

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am a newbie in android programming and I am trying to create a counter on the ActionBar (In my case Toolbar).
I have already added the background(a circle) but now I need to put in a next(number) which decreases as a result of a button.
Sorry for my bad english and I hope someone can help me, I need only a code base for start working on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mex_box"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_brightness_1_black_36dp"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/mex_counter"
    android:visible="true"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

<item
android:id="@+id/users_list"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_black_36dp"
    android:title="@string/contacts_list"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:visible="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menu.clear(); // clears all menu items..
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_action_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys but my counter is an item of the action buttons, not the logo or the title

Comment: Uh the title says how to dynamically change the action bar icon thats why i post that answer

Comment: What have you [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Post your code.

Comment: I have not tried nothing, I have only used this:

Comment: public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menu.clear(); // clears all menu items..
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_action_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

Comment: "I have not tried nothing", this is your first mistake. Did you click on the [link I provided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? You will improve your chances of getting an good (or correct) answer if your try to research and figure it out yourself first, people want to help those who are willing to help themselves. Not trying to be off-putting, just some friendly advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues on your hands. First is displaying text within a circle, or bubble. Second, you want to be able to display that text in your `Toolbar` (or `ActionBar`), with the ability to change the text.

To solve your first issue, I would suggest creating a `ShapeDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FF000000" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"  
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"/>

</shape>
```

You may need to mess with the radius of `8dp`, to make it look more circular, but this will allow the view to expand no matter how long the text gets. Lastly, create a layout that uses this `ShapeDrawable` as a background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp" android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
    android:background="@drawable/label_shape_drawable"/>
```

To solve your second issue, you can use this `TextView` as an `ActionLayout` for your `MenuItem`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/mex_box" android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/mex_counter" android:visible="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" app:actionLayout="@layout/view_label"/>
```

Then you can obtain your `TextView` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`:

```
private TextView mLabelTextView;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_action_menu, menu);

    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mex_box);
    mLabelTextView = (TextView) menuItem.getActionView();

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then, with your `TextView` on hand, you can change the text whenever you like:

```
mLabelTextView.setText(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // use whatever id you have for your toolbar
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Then set whatever number you need as the title in the `onClickListener` of your button:

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("" + number - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys but my counter is an item of the action buttons, not the logo or the title

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem a little more.

Comment: I have a black circle icon as action bar button, now I need to put in a number to change dinamically or put as icon a black circle with a numer (ex. 15) and as a result of a button click, the icon will change with antoher as a balck circle with 14

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this function where **resId** is your drawable id:

```
public void setHomeAsUpIndicator(int resId) {
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys but my counter is an item of the action buttons, not the logo or the title